# Viewport objects became transparent gray

Tags: 3d-view

My viewport was working normally halfway through this project, but all the objects became a light transparent gray.

[image]

I now see very little definition, and can't really select faces. How do I turn this back to the standard?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to have the *X-Ray* disabled in the *Viewport Shading* popover.

[image]